# Editing Regex Code

Tags: regex

I am hoping someone can help me with what I think is a regex problem.

I have a program which takes a piece of html code and extracts phone numbers from it and separates them by semi colons. What I would like to do is change this so that it extracts anything between two specific text strings with backslashes in between. For example

```
stringone/******/stringtwo
stringone/876876876876876/stringtwo
stringone/abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz/stringtwo
```

Before and after the total string there may or may not be spaces, letters, numbers or special characters.

I have really tried with regex but I can't get this figured out. I assume (and only by instinct) that the line that needs changing is this one:

```
    .Pattern = "(\+([\d \(\)-]+){10,15})|((\d( |-))?\(?\d{2,4}\)?( |-)\d{3,4}( |-)\d{3,4})|(\d{3,4}( |-)\d{7})"
```

But the entire code is as follows:

```
Function Main ( strText )

    dim strResult

    strResult = Extract_Phone_Numbers ( strText )

    Main = strResult

End Function

' This function extracts phone numbers from a specific string using pattern matching (a regular expression).

Function Extract_Phone_Numbers ( strText )

    dim strResult

    Set RegularExpressionObject = New RegExp

    With RegularExpressionObject
    .Pattern = "(\+([\d \(\)-]+){10,15})|((\d( |-))?\(?\d{2,4}\)?( |-)\d{3,4}( |-)\d{3,4})|(\d{3,4}( |-)\d{7})"
    .IgnoreCase = True
    .Global = True
    End With

    Set objMatches = RegularExpressionObject.Execute( strText )

    For Each objMatch in objMatches
        If ( InStr ( strResult, objMatch.value ) = 0  )  Then
            If ( Len ( strResult ) > 0  )  Then
                strResult = strResult + "; "
            End If      
            strResult = strResult + objMatch.value
        End If      
    Next

    Set RegularExpressionObject = nothing

    strResult = Trim ( strResult )

    Extract_Phone_Numbers = strResult

End Function
```

Can anyone help me to get this changed?

Comment: Sorry, can you please confirm what language we're looking at?

Comment: @zx81 I know this sounds crazy, but I don't actually know. I am attempting to mod something as opposed to building it from scratch. That being said, I "think" it is a VBscript.

Comment: That's fantastic! lol =) Hey, see my answer, are you matching several in one file, or extracting the strings one at a time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. In general, the pattern for matching your pattern is `stringone/[^/]*/stringtwo`, including the slashes
2. To match inside, but not including the slashes, there are several ways. If your flavor supports lookarounds, go with this: `(?<=stringone/)[^/]*(?=/stringtwo)`
3. VBS doesn't support lookbehind, so we need to match the whole string, capturing the wanted part to Group 1: `stringone/([^/]*)/stringtwo`

On [the demo](http://regex101.com/r/pH3tO8), look at the Group 1 captures in the right pane. Note that in this regex tester the slashes had to be escaped.

**Explanation**

`stringone/` matches a literal `stringone/`, then the negated character class `[^/]` matches one character that is not a `/`, and the `*` quantifier repeats that 0 or more times, then we match the final `/stringtwo`.

Comment: Hey zx81. There will be multiple instances on the page, which I am hoping will be separated in the output by the semi columns. It also has to be between the specific words, "stringone/" and "/stringtwo".

Comment: FYI fixed answer, added demo. :)

Comment: I know I am pushing it, but where does this code in relation to the original code? I tried replacing the entire code but it isn't working.

Comment: Sorry, can't help with that code, just the regex (see [captures of demo in the right pane](http://regex101.com/#pcre)). :( The pattern `stringone/([^/]*)/stringtwo` goes in place of your `.Pattern =` string... Not sure the exact syntax to retrieve Group 1. Hopefully someone will come along to help. :)

Comment: I forgot to change "stringone" and "stringtwo" to my strings :). this works perfectly. Thanks so much for your help.